How to set matplotlib spacing when using xlim. Or is it possible to use margins() with xlim()?
Per default, matplotlib always adds whitespace between your first data points and the axis like you can see in the image:
Default Plot with whitespace between data and axis. The following Code was used:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)
plt.show()

Now when I add a xlim with ax.set_xlim(2), then the spacing list gone:

How can I limit the axes but also use spacing (so that the line does not touch the axes)?
Edit: So my desired output looks like this:

I tried to use margins(), but it seems like it does not work together with xlim/ylim regardless of the order I call them.

To plot only a subset of a dataset a good approach is to trim the data to what you need as that allows matplotlib's formatting to work as normal.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

I am using numpy for the arrange and speed for large datasets.
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # some dataset

This would work with any dataset with no extra work beyond adjusting your range.
range_to_plot = (2,4) # setting a range to plot min and max values

This range is a minimum and maximum value on the x axis to plot. Simply set to length of data for only setting a lower limit.
x_values = np.arange(len(data)) # x values for the data
data_to_plot = np.array(data, dtype=float) # data to plot

data_to_plot[x_values < range_to_plot[0]] = np.nan # setting values outside the range to nan
data_to_plot[x_values > range_to_plot[1]] = np.nan # setting values outside the range to nan

Creating an array for the x axis values makes working with the axis more straight forward. Setting values in the data to plot to nan s if outside our set range on the x axis.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_values, data_to_plot)
ax.set_xlim(range_to_plot[0]-0.1, range_to_plot[1]+0.1)
plt.show()

Our set_xlim includes offsets outwith the range we have plotted to give a whitespace between the axis and the plotted line.
This produces a graph like this:


Note that this would only work if the split point is also a point in the dataset. For example if you want to set the lower X to 2.5 it wouldn't work

It would only work if the split point is a value in the set of x axis points.

Thank you, I hoped there exist a matplot solution but this seems like a good workaround!

If you check ax.get_xlim() from your original command and you'll see:
ax.get_xlim()
# (-0.2, 4.2)

This blank space is actually 0.2 units on each side.
You should just do the same:
ax.set_xlim(2-0.2)

Output:

If you don't want the line to touch the axis it's a bit more complex, you have to clip it with a mask:
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)

# change the axis
ax.set_xlim(2-0.2)

# create a mask
x0, x1 = 2, 4
y0, y1 = 1, 5

mask = Rectangle((x0, y0), x1-x0, y1-y0, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none')
ax.add_artist(mask)

# clip all the lines with the mask
for line in ax.lines:
    line.set_clip_path(mask)

Output:


Thanks for your answer, but then the blue line is still touching the yaxis. I editet my question to make it more clear and added an image of the desired output

@flx see the update, you further have to clip it

You can define a box to clip any Matplotlib artist.  Note that it has to be in the display coordinate system so here I use the transData transform to get from the data coordinates to that.  See the Transforms Tutorial for more details.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox, TransformedBbox

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Create a box in data coordinates and transform it to display coordinates.
bbox = TransformedBbox(Bbox([[2, 2], [4, 5]]), ax.transData)
line, = ax.plot(data)
line.set_clip_box(bbox)
plt.show()


